# SQL innerjoin convert integer to text

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an *SQL database directorydb* that holds two tables: departments and persons.

**Departments**:

```
Department ID (INT, PK, auto-incrementing, deptID)
Name (VARCHAR(50), deptName) 
Phone Number (VARCHAR(20), deptPhone)
Email (VARCHAR(50), deptEmail)
Office Location (VARCHAR(100), deptOffice)
```

**Persons**:

```
Person ID (INT, PK, auto-incrementing, persID)
Email Address (VARCHAR(50), persEmail)
Password (VARCHAR (50), persPassword)
First Name (VARCHAR(50), persFName)
Last Name (VARCHAR(50), persLName)
Phone Number (VARCHAR(20), persPhone)
Office Location (VARCHAR(100), persOffice)
Department (INT, persDept)
```

I need to list all of the people in the persons table in a **PHP** file, but I need to replace the *integer* in *persDept* with the plain text *deptName* in the **departments** table.

I appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Please show what you've tried. We won't write the query for you, but we will help you when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple join. Using explicit INNER JOIN syntax:-

```
SELECT a.`Person ID`,
    a.`Email Address`,
    a.`Password`,
    a.`First Name`,
    a.`Last Name`,
    a.`Phone Number`,
    a.`Office Location`,
    b.`Name` AS deptName
FROM persons a
INNER JOIN departments b
ON a.Department = b.`Department ID`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a simple join like this:

```
Select b.name, a.* from departments a join persons b on a.departmentid=b.departmentid
```